# magento 2 installation on MAMP. none of the pages work

Tags: magento2

I installed MAMP on a MAC PRO.

I then successfully installed magento 2.

The Homepage works. However none of the other pages seem to work. They  all returns a

```
Not Found
The requested URL /magentotwo/customer/account/create/ was not found on this server.
```

I presume this might have something to do with the module-rewrite of apache etc.

i did place the following in my apache

**httpd.conf :**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName magento.com
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT;

when i place an index.php after the base url it works; i.e

> http://localhost:8888/magentotwo/index.php/customer/account/create/

However, i am still not able to log into admin. so this does not work:

> http://localhost:8888/magentotwo/index.php/admin

i am also not able to change my host address to just:

> http://localhost/magentotwo/index.php/customer/account/create/

Is there something else that needs to done in MAMP/htaccess files for mamp  that i am missing i am missing.

I previously  used WAMP the pages worked by default.

SECOND EDIT---

i tried the following but it still does not work:

in my config i placed the following
 **httpd.conf :** 
NameVirtualHost *:80

```
ServerName magento.dev
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all  
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i then sudo vi into my host files and changed local host i,e

sudo vi /etc/hosts

and then changed

> 127.0.0.1       localhost magento.dev

i then tried to access site at

> http://magento.dev/

and

> https://localhost/magento.dev/

but nothing appears

```
error message; 
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
```

Comment: try using following url `/magentotwo/index.php/customer/account/create/`

Comment: also drop your localhost full url is it something like this "http://localhost/magentotwo/"

Comment: @AmanAlam. hi. the localhost/magentotwo does not work. however when i placed the index.php it does work. so. is my problem to do with the htaccess file. i have edited my question to reflect the change

Comment: problem is your apache `rewrite_module` is not enabled please check it

Comment: Next please enable `Search Engine Optimization` option from `admin->store->configuration->general->web->Search Engine Optimization->YES`

Comment: @AmanAlam where do i go in MAMP TO check it

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName magento.com
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from all  
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
 </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: You should try above configuration may also resolve your issue

Comment: could you do this as an official answer. that way i can mark it as correct if it works. it will help other people new to MAMP

Comment: @AmanAlam could you do this as an official answer. that way i can mark it as correct if it works. it will help other people new to MAMP

Comment: Yes i writing will add it now

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible solution for your problem:

**Solution 1**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName magento.com
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all  
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Solution 2**:
Check `Search Engine Optimization` option enabled in admin or not.
To check it you can check this step `Admin->Store->Configuration->General->Web->Search Engine Optimization->YES`

Comment: hi. it did not work. i have edited by question to show the problem

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47526/enable-url-rewriting-mod-rewrite-using-htaccess-files-in-sites-on-lion

Comment: check above ink answer and check if all is looks like provided answer

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I updated to Magento2.4.2 from Magento2.3.5. On local host keep `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` the same. Then add virtual host at the bottom of file, but make sure the virtual host file path is pointing towards the pub folder in Magento.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 127.0.0.1
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo/pub/
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magentotwo/pub/">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all  
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then if you appended a directory name to your server’s hostname or IP address to create the base URL when you installed Magento (for example `http://192.168.33.10/magento2`), you’ll need to remove it. I would remove from core_config_data table in database both base and secure urls to be the same and remove the `/magento2` and just keep `http://192.168.33.10/`.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://192.168.33.10/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 3;
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Then you could remove index.php urls by setting Search Engine Optimization to Yes from No.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need top set values for MAGE_RUN_TYPE and MAGE_RUN_CODE using the Apache server variable SetEnvIf in a virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName          mysite.mg
   DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName          french.mysite.mg
   DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "french"
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName          german.mysite.mg
   DocumentRoot        /var/www/html/magento2/pub/
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "german"
   SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
</VirtualHost>
```

It works for me.

Please refer here for details : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Hope this works for you as well.